# Second group cohomology group of compact Lie group is finite?

Tags: lie-groups, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I suspect that if $G$ is a compact Lie group, that $H^2_\textrm{group}(G;U(1))$ is finite. (For example: $H^2_\textrm{group}(SO(3);U(1)) = \mathbb Z_2$)

I couldn't easily find this statement though, and I can't quite prove it. I think the following should be correct:
$$H^2_\textrm{group}(G;U(1)) \cong H^2(BG;U(1)) \cong H^2(G;\mathbb Z)$$

Hence, what I want to show is equivalent to showing that the singular cohomolgoy $H^2(G;\mathbb Z)$ is purely torsion. Or again, equivalently, that $H^2_\textrm{dR}(G) \cong H^2(G;\mathbb R) = 0$.

Can anyone confirm this, or give a counter-example?

Comment: Maybe it could help that the second homotopy group of a compact Lie group is trivial. And using that there is a surjective homomorphism from the second homotopy group to the second homology group?

Comment: combined with the universal coefficients theorem for cohomology..... it is just an idea and I have said some things without checking the details.

Comment: @D1811994 Thanks! I agree, that should do the trick :)

Comment: @D1811994 I tried to work out the details but I'm stuck. It is indeed true that $H^2(G;\mathbb Z) \cong Z^\beta \oplus T$ where $\beta$ is the rank of $H_2(G;\mathbb Z)$ and $T$ is the torsion of $H_1(G;\mathbb Z)$, but I don't see why $\pi_2(X) \to H_2(X;\mathbb Z)$ should be surjective? (with $X$ a Lie group)

Comment: You are right. I was thinking in using Hurewicz Theorem such as in the answer given by @Michael Albanese to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620953/on-the-surjectivity-of-the-hurewicz-homomorphism/1620958

Comment: However, I think we can't apply Hurewicz Theorem as I had in mind here. Sorry for my blunder!

Comment: By the way, $H^2(S^1\times S^1;\mathbb{Z})\cong H^2(T^2;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$ (using Poincaré Duality, for example). And $S^1\times S^1$ is a compact Lie group....

Comment: Maybe there is a kind of result you could be interested in here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01388548

Comment: But, considering the example of the torus $T^2$, it seems that what you are trying to prove is not true without further hypothesis. I hope this helps, and sorry again for my blunder.

Comment: @D1811994 Thank you very much for your counter-example! If you post it as answer, I can accept it. (It also helped me realize that the actual statement I was looking for is that $H^2_\textrm{grp}(G;U(1))$ is discrete, i.e. that $H^2(G;\mathbb Z)$ is finite-dimensional, which is in fact well-known for compact Lie groups :) This is to be contrasted to e.g. $H^2_\textrm{grp}(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z; U(1)) = U(1)$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to post the comment as an answer. We will provide a counterexample. Consider the torus $S^1\times S^1$. It is a compact Lie group since it is the product of two compact Lie groups. However, by Poincaré duality (or computing it directly), we have $H^2(S^1\times S^1,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$.